# Leaflet populate L.divIcon marker's html option from feature properties

Tags: leaflet, labeling, markers

I am using Leaflet.js to make a timeline-based playback of marker locations, using a [Leaflet Playback](https://github.com/hallahan/LeafletPlayback) listed on Leaflet Plugins.

I am defining an `L.divIcon` earlier in my code:

```js
var busIcon = L.divIcon({className: 'bus-div-icon', html:"1"});
```

And later on I have to pass it to the plugin's function:

```js
var playbackOptions = {
  //...
  marker: {
    icon : busIcon,
    getPopup: function(featureData) {
      // returns something using featureData.properties.name, so here a function works
    }
  },
  //...
```

**I want to populate the `html` variable in the `divIcon` dynamically**, similarly to how `getPopup` has been defined (this code I have copied and customized from the plugin's documentation example).

But when I try to pass a function to the `icon`:

```js
icon: function(featureData) {
  return L.divIcon({className: 'bus-div-icon', html: 
  featureData.properties.busnum });
},
```

It did not work; I got this error in my console:

> Uncaught TypeError: t.icon.createIcon is not a function
>      at e._initIcon (leaflet.js:5)
>      at e.onAdd (leaflet.js:5)
>      at e._layerAdd (leaflet.js:5)
>      at e.whenReady (leaflet.js:5)
>      at e.addLayer (leaflet.js:5)
>      at e.addTo (leaflet.js:5)
>      at e.addTrack (LeafletPlayback.min.js:1)
>      at e.addData (LeafletPlayback.min.js:1)
>      at e.setData (LeafletPlayback.min.js:1)
>      at e.initialize (LeafletPlayback.min.js:1)

I tried another strategy, and no errors this time:

```js
icon: L.divIcon({
  className: 'bus-div-icon',
  html: function(featureData) {
    console.log("Hello!");
    return '1';
  }
}),
```

..  but the results were hilarious!

[image: Imgur]

What happened here is that instead of executing the function, it has displayed that whole code as text on the map! See screenshot above.

How to populate `html` dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beauty of Leaflet is that can "easily" customize the behaviour of its classes, including for plugins which follow Leaflet classes conventions.

Therefore you can customize how LeafletPlayback plugin creates its `MoveableMarker`, so that it uses a new "`getIcon`" function that you would pass in the options, similarly to the [`getPopup`](https://github.com/hallahan/LeafletPlayback/blob/5fc4568173fe6a5d47ccbd07040a04fb2cf9d093/src/MoveableMarker.js#L16-L18) option that you mention:

```js
L.Playback.MoveableMarker.include({
  _originalInitialize: L.Playback.MoveableMarker.prototype.initialize,
  initialize: function(startLatLng, options, feature) {
    // Perform some operations before doing the normal initialization.
    var marker_options = options.marker || {};

    // "Dynamically" assign the icon.
    if (marker_options.getIcon) {
      marker_options.icon = marker_options.getIcon(feature);
    }

    // Now perform the normal initialization.
    this._originalInitialize.call(this, startLatLng, options, feature);
  }
});
```

Now you can pass `marker.getIcon` option to `new L.Playback`, which will receive the feature data as parameter, so that you can build your icon accordingly.

Example based on the plugin [example 0](https://github.com/hallahan/LeafletPlayback/blob/5fc4568173fe6a5d47ccbd07040a04fb2cf9d093/examples/example_0.html): https://plnkr.co/edit/8GQHHfzE9qkvPEb20pGn?p=preview

EDIT: changed `marker_options.getIcon(this.feature);` to `marker_options.getIcon(feature);` as that's the one carrying the feature data.

Comment: hi @ghybs, the plnkr link is down, FYI. I was getting stuck with `getIcon: function(featureData) {..}` : the featureData was coming as invalid. Then I looked at the original `LeafletPlayback.js`  and found that we have to pass `feature` to `getIcon` in your code snippet, not `this.feature`. Now it works!